# Why Android browser show itself as "Safari" and "Chrome" in user agent string?

Tags: android, google-chrome, browser, safari, user-agent

I am confused that lots of android browser show itself as "Safari" and "Chrome" in user agent string. Is it they need to spoof to server to get complete content?

There are some user agent string I found in different browser.

```
AOSP Browser (Mobile Mode)
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.2 HTC_One_E8 Build/LRX22G) AppleWebKit 537.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/ 33.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36

AOSP Browser (Desktop Mode)
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, Like Gecko) Chrome/ 33.0.0.0 Safari/534.24

Chrome (Mobile Mode)
Mozilla/5.0. (Linux; Android 5.0.2 HTC_One_E8 Build/LRX22G) AppleWebKit 537.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.83 Mobile Safari/537.36

Chrome (Desktop Mode)
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.83 Safari/537.36

Dolphin (Mobile Mode)
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.2; HTC_One_E8 Build/LRX22G) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/537.36 Chrome/33.0.0.0

Dolphin (Desktop Mode)
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10) AppleWebKit/537.16 (KHTML, Like Gecko) Version/8.0 Safari/537.16

Firefox (Mobile Mode)
Mozilla/5.0 (Android 5.0.2; Mobile rv:43.0) Gecko/43.0 Firefox/43.0

Firefox (Desktop Mode)
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64 rv:43.0) Gecko/43.0 Firefox/43.0

Opera
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux;Android 5.0.2; HTC One_E8 build/ LRX22G) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/ 47.0.2526.73 Mobile Safari/537.36 OPR/ 34.0.2044.98679

Sleipnir
Mozilla/5.0 () (Linux;Android 5.0.2; HTC One_E8 build/ LRX22G) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/ 46.0.2526.73 Mobile Safari/537.36 Sleipnir/3.5.2
```

Comment: maybe because its using the Apple webkit -- check here for a complete list  -- http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Browserlist/

Comment: So funny, every browser is "like Gecko" now... http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/

Comment: thanks for the article. It's funny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AOSP Browser uses a WebView for its implementation. The current WebView is based on Chrome/Chromium source.

For each version of Android, the Webview Chromium version is different (https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview#what_version_of_chrome_is_it_based_on_). The fact that the device listed above is reporting Android 5.0.2 and Chrome version 33.0.0.0 seems odd given that the AOSP Browser was deprecated in Android versions >= 4.4.

Any application that uses a WebView, other than the AOSP Browser, may report the same user-agent string unless that application explicitly modifies it.

For more information on the user agent string in WebViews: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview#what_is_the_default_user_agent_